# How to get all cells data in a selected row using DataGridView in WindowsForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a DataGridView showing some data from my database and when I double click any row in the datagridview I get its contents in a new window.

I have this:

```
 private void ListaProductos_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
 var content = ListaProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
 var abrirNuevoProducto = new modificar_producto(content ); // I want to pass data to another form
 abrirNuevoProducto.Show(); // loads the new form with data for modification
 }
```

This worked for me but... it would be tired and tedious to make this one by one like this:

```
var content = ListaProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
var content2 = ListaProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
var conten3 = ListaProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Surname"].Value.ToString();
var content4 = ListaProductos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Address"].Value.ToString();
... and 150 more columns
 var abrirNuevoProducto = new modificar_producto(content, content2, content3, content4 ... and so on); // I want to pass data to another form
 abrirNuevoProducto.Show(); // loads the new form with data for modification
```

I would do this using a List but..., I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this because the way I am trying is very tired and poor. Or Should I use a list instead?

I need to pass data to another form for modification operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a class defined for this table you can use code as below

```
var products = new List<Products>(grid.SelectedRows.Count);

for(int index = 0; index < grid.SelectedRows.Count; index++)
{
   var selectedRow = grid.SelectedRows[index];
   var product = (Products)selectedRow.DataBoundItem;

   products.Add(prduct);
}
```

or if you don't have a class definition you can use dynamic keyword

```
var products = new List<dynamic>(grid.SelectedRows.Count);

for(int index = 0; index < grid.SelectedRows.Count; index++)
{
   var selectedRow = grid.SelectedRows[index];
   var product = (dynamic)selectedRow.DataBoundItem;

   products.Add(prduct);
}
```

Comment: Will this work even if using a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e` ? I am using an event CellDoubleClick